# Character Class and Anchors in C# Regex

Tags: c#, regex

I have a regex that doesn't match...

```
string command = "browser help";
Match match = Regex.Match(command, @"^browser\s[help]$");

if(match.Success == false) {
    Console.WriteLine("Doesn't match");
}
```

Yet, this matches...

```
Match match = Regex.Match(command, @"^browser\shelp$");
```

I'm not actually asking for someone to solve this for me, just tell me why.

Thank you.

Comment: What exactly you trying to match ?

Comment: The `command` string variable. I was going to add "^browser\s[help\s[load|go|close]]" but that doesn't work.

Comment: so you basically need to match the word browser followed by any of a pre-defined set of words? For example help, load, close, etc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not clear what you're asking. But it's worth noting that the square brackets in a regex indicate a set of characters. So the expression "[help]" means match *one* character, where that character is 'h', 'e', 'l', or 'p'.

If you want to match some selection of words, use parentheses. E.g. "(load|go|close)".

Comment: That works. I was under the wrong impression what a character class does. Thanks.